# How to create a ContextMenu animation like in the native iOS Files app?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I have a `CollectionView` with album cells looking like the ones in the photos app. I want to apply a ContextMenu to those cells. But by doing so the `ContextMenu` animation is applied onto the whole cell which doesn't look nice. What I want to achieve is the animation only to affect the `UIImageView` inside the cell without the labels below the image.

This is how it looks right now during the animation. You can clearly see the shadow going around the labels at the bottom.

[image]

This is how it looks like in the Files app. That's what I want to achieve. The animation is only applied to the folder image, not the labels below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add the content menu on the image and not on the Stack (or whatever you use to group the items).

The following code produces the following example:
[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
      var body: some View {
          VStack{
              Image("swift").resizable().frame(width: 200, height: 200).border(Color.black).contextMenu {
                  Text("Menu Item 1")
                  Text("Menu Item 2")
                  Text("Menu Item 3")
              }

              Text("Label").font(.title)
          }
      }
  }
```